# C++: Move Constructor throwing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, variable-assignment, move

Please, lords of stackoverflow, have mercy on me. My assignment is due in an hour and everything works -- except I can't for the life of me figure out why my move-constructor (and by extension, my copy-assignment) throws a segmentation fault!

Extra info if it helps: the program is to make a data structure called a Chain which basically stores an array of any data type, and a size_t with the size.

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need any more info!

```
// Copy-constructor.
Chain(const Chain &rhs) {
    size_ = rhs.size();
    array_ = new Object[size_];
    for (int i = 0; i < size_; i++) {
        array_[i] = rhs.array_[i];
    }
}

// Copy-assignment.
Chain& operator=(const Chain &rhs) {
    Chain copy = rhs;
    std::swap(*this, copy);
    return *this;
}

// Move-constructor.
Chain(Chain &&rhs) {
    rhs.array_ = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Your move constructor doesn't actually set any of the class members, so future operations are likely to fail...

Comment: True. I don't think that's the issue here, though -- my implementation was exactly what my professor suggested.

Comment: @BowmanBeric then your professor is wrong. Or you misunderstood what was told to you.

Answer (score 2):

Your move constructor is wrong. It is not moving the input object's array to take ownership of it, and is not setting any of the data members of the object being constructed. It should look more like this instead:

```
Chain(Chain &&rhs) {
    size_ = rhs.size();
    array_ = rhs.array_;
    rhs.array_ = nullptr;
    rhs.size_ = 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
Chain(Chain &&rhs) : array_(nullptr), size_(0) {
    std::swap(size_, rhs.size_);
    std::swap(array_, rhs.array_);
}
```

On a side note, your assignment operator can be simplified so it can act as both copy-assignment and move-assignment:

```
Chain& operator=(Chain rhs) {
    std::swap(*this, rhs);
    return *this;
}
```